# Problem with ImageButton in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to create two ImageButton in an activity but I can only see one of these. Someone can help me?

```
activity_ristorante.xml :


  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".Ristoranti">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="232dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Class:

```
public class Ristoranti extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
    ImageButton b2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);

    b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.putia) ;
    b2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pos);


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://maps.app.goo.gl/FoRGA2CbJdrV5cfT8");
            Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

what's errors? I can't see the button even though it's set to "visible" within android studioCan you help me? thank you

Comment: Your setContentView uses a different XML layout than the one you posted

Comment: ah, thank you very much, I'm new to java and android studio and I'm still learning!

Answer (score 1):

Just change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_ristorante);` or copy your XML code from **activity_ristorante.xml** to **activity_main.xml**